# Double dot product of two tensors

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have two tensors: `A` is a second order tensor and `B` is a fourth order tensor. I know that when computing the [double dot product (:)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Product_of_dyadic_and_dyadic) of two tensors, the rank of the resulting tensor will be decreased by two, so in my example the result should be a second order tensor.

However, when I write this code in MATLAB, it gives the following error:

> Matrix dimensions must agree.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: 1. provide some code to show how the tensors are represented and also how you are doing the product.
2. by **double dot product** do you mean `(:)` operator in MATLAb like `A(:)`?

Comment: You have not provided ANY code. How can we know what you are doing wrong?

Comment: @ISarasky Did you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [colon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) operator in MATLAB doesn't do what you expect, as it serves another functionality. In fact, there is no built-in implementation for a double inner product in MATLAB. You need to implement it by yourself, for instance:

```
idx = max(0, ndims(A) - 1); %// Index of first common dimension
B_t = permute(B, circshift(1:ndims(A) + ndims(B), [0, idx - 1]));
double_dot_prod = squeeze(sum(squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, A, B_t), idx)), idx));
```

where `A` and `B` are your tensors (*i.e* multi-dimensional matrices). Vectorizing this was a hard nut to crack, so I hope I got the math right!

If you want, you can put this code in a function for convenience. For the sake of good practice, also verify that both tensors are of second rank or higher. Here's a friendly copy-paste version for you:

```
function C = double_dot(A, B)
    assert(~isvector(A) && ~isvector(B))
    idx = max(0, ndims(A) - 1);
    B_t = permute(B, circshift(1:ndims(A) + ndims(B), [0, idx - 1]));
    C = squeeze(sum(squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, A, B_t), idx)), idx));
```

A word of advice: I suggest that you read online tutorials to get yourself familiar with  the basics of the MATLAB language.

Comment: Thank you Eitan for your guidance.

Comment: My goodness, how did you manage to vectorise that beast?! Good work!

Answer (score 2):

It's very unfortunate, but MATLAB has not implemented an inner product of tensors in their standard library to my knowledge. To produce a scalar version of the inner product, you need to either inefficiently iterate through each entry like:

```
function C = double_dot(A,B)
    for i=1:1:3
        for j=1:1:3
            C = C + A(i,j)*B(i,j);
        end
    end
```

Or you can run a slight modification of Eitan's vectorized code (above). His code produces a vector. The inner product of two tensors should be a scalar. So you need to sum across the final array that his code produces.

```
function C = double_dot(A, B)
    assert(~isvector(A) && ~isvector(B))
    idx = max(0, ndims(A) - 1);
    B_t = permute(B, circshift(1:ndims(A) + ndims(B), [0, idx - 1]));
    C = sum(squeeze(sum(squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, A, B_t), idx)), idx)));
```

Eitan's code is an implementation of the `dot` function in matlab (see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dot.html). Note the section on the dot product of matricies. Instead you should more simply use:

```
function C = double_dot(A,B)
    C = sum(dot(A,B));
```