# Double Dot product in Arrayfire

Tags: c++, dot-product, arrayfire

I want to compute **double dot product** in **Arrayfire**. is there any function in **arrayfire** to use for double dot product.
This is my tensor, that I wish to impelment:

```
AA:(E_iE_i - c^2I)
where, A--> 2D-array ; E_i --> 1D array (defined as col. vec in arrayfire)
c --> scalar/constant ; I --> identity matrix
```

Any suggestion, reference, plz.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayFire does not provide a double dot product function, but you can define your own.

Assuming a definition of double dot product consistent with the one given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471794/double-dot-product-of-two-tensors) and [here](https://www.continuummechanics.org/tensornotationbasic.html), the "double dot product" is the sum of all values after computing an element-wise multiplication of the two matrices. The two matrices must have the same shape:

```cpp
af::array doubledot(af::array a, af::array b) {
  return af::sum(a * b);
}
```